# Django query with related models

Tags: python, django

For the below models:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)

class OrderA(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    foo = models.FloatField()
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
    type = models.IntegerField()

class OrderB(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
    type = models.IntegerField()
```

I want to grab all the Customer objects with their related OrderA and OrderB objects in one go for a condition (where type in OrderA and OrderB equals 1)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You're right in your comment to Ignacio that `select_related` works in the opposite direction.

I've written about a technique to do it in this direction [on my blog](http://blog.roseman.org.uk/2010/01/11/django-patterns-part-2-efficient-reverse-lookups/) (sorry about the plug).

Comment: This is why you should not answer with a link... because now the link is not working and therefore the answer is not usefull

Comment: Well, the problem appears to be with my blog's DNS, not with the link itself. But that solution is now outdated for another reason, which is that you should now use `prefetch_related`.

Answer (score 3):

[`select_related()`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) will pre-populate the appropriate attributes:

```
Customer.objects.filter(ordera_set__type=1, orderb_set__type=1).select_related()
```

Comment: Are you sure the select_related works in this direction? In my understanding if you call it on OrderA or OrderB object then it will populate all the related Customer objects.

Comment: Is it same as: `Customer.objects.select_related('ordera', 'orderb').filter(ordera_set__type=1, orderb_set__type=1)`

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this way:

```
Customer.objects.get(orderA__type=1, orderB__type=1)
```

I hope it's helpful to you